# Global variable jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need *jsondata*  variable to be global so I can use it later on in the script.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    data: {term: $("#tags").val()},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(out) {
        var jsondata = $.map(out, function(item) {          
            return {
                label: item[0]
            };                                  
        });
```